# GetMember by MetadataToken

Tags: c#, reflection

What is the proper way of getting a member of a type using a metadata token of that member (with reflection)?

I've tried:

```
MemberInfo mi = type.GetMembers(bindingFlags).FirstOrDefault(m => m.MetadataToken == metadataToken);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Module* class provides a set of *Resolve* methods that can find the member, e.g.

```
MemberInfo mi = type.Module.ResolveMember(metadataToken);
```

Edit: *ResolveMember* cannot resolve properties and events, so the originally suggested approach has to be used.