# Why is there no .NET RuntimePropertyHandle and PropertyInfo.GetPropertyFromHandle?

Tags: .net, cil

I've seen the following .NET types and functions for `Type`, `FieldInfo`, and `MethodInfo`:

```
RuntimeTypeHandle th = ...;
Type t = Type.GetTypeFromHandle(th);

RuntimeFieldHandle fh = ...;
FieldInfo f = FieldInfo.GetFieldFromHandle(fh);

RuntimeMethodHandle mh = ...;
MethodInfo m = MethodBase.GetMethodFromHandle(mh);
```

However, there doesn't appear to be a corresponding handle type and `Get...FromHandle` for properties.  Is there one I'm not seeing, or is there some good reason why these don't exist?

It seems very inefficient to have to lookup the `PropertyInfo` using `Type.GetProperty` when I already have access to property tokens for the properties I'm interested in.

Comment: I wonder, where do you get the handles and tokens? Not that it matters, just curious.

Comment: @James because you have Get...FromHandle for filed and method and properties and events are filed and methods. There is not such a thing like property in the metadata its just C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [coreclr](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/runtimehandles.h) shows, properties and events have no handles, therefore no `Runtime...Handle` or `Get...FromHandle` for them. Thinking of a "handle" is simply invalid in their context.

As to why, I guess the reason is that properties and events are purely metadata things, while methods and fields are much more. There are CIL opcodes for accessing methods, fields and types, but none for properties or events. Using those is compiled to CIL as using one of their respective accessor methods. They are literally nothing more than pieces of metadata for the runtime, so they need no handles.

I have myself asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26701470/getmember-by-metadatatoken), and there are really limited number of resolving methods for properties and events. As for your underlying question, I suppose enumerating over all properties and looking for `MetadataToken` might be more efficient than using `GetProperty`, but I'd rather test that.